# JQwidgets grid not showing special character

Tags: javascript, jqxgrid, jqxwidgets, jqwidget

I am having grid which i am trying to fill with some dynamic data but it seems that the grid itself not showing some characters for that i provided the grid some raw data as

```
     var firstNames =
    [
        "Andrew", "DI<Value Provider", "Shelley", "Regina", "Yoshi"
    ];
```

the result is like

> Andrew DI Shelly Regina Yoshi

Please provide some suggestion or help in this regard . Here the character after < not appearing in result part including < character .

Answer (score 2):

The Grid displays HTML in the cells so you would probably need to mask your < character as &lt;